# "java.lang.runtimeexception: org.xml.sax.saxparseexception; linenumber: 1; columnnumber: caused by: org.xml.sax.saxparseexception"

Tags: java, exception, runtime, jdk1.7

I am the devtools test suite on java test harness but getting this saxparse exception after running the testcase. what is the root cause? i am using oracle jdk1.7.

I have tried validating the xml document with xsd but it is valid.

Comment: We need to see the [error trace](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)